# Java applet shop safety

Tags: java, security, paypal, applet

I have a theoretical question. Lets say I will create shopping cart using java and put it on the website as a applet. Nothing complicated just let customer to select object, and after pressing pay button, I would receive mail with order detail, and user would be redirected to the paypal to pay for it. I really can not find any way how someone would abuse it so I believe it supposed to be safe, since all payment would be done with paypal.

Comment: I wouldn't call Java safe: http://www.us-cert.gov/cas/techalerts/TA13-010A.html

Comment: E-commerce sites are supposed to attract customers by being functional on a wide variety of platforms.  The difficulties involved with applets are quite likely to have the precise opposite effect.  Do you feel comfortable chasing away everyone on iOS or IE10?

Comment: Well looks like you are right, I will use action script than to make it with flash, it looks quite similar to java.. thanks.

Comment: Right, because Flash has never had any security issues. I wouldn't do Flash or applets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java applets are run on the user's machine. Any data they send to you is potentially altered (price, account, etc.) So although you may receive a price form that represents a valid order you would need to have validation on your end to ensure the haven't played with the order details.

From there, the unique order ID it should generate can be linked to the paypal order from the server end (not using the direct input from the user) and can likely trust the result.